# JavaScript; creating and using an object method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a newbie to web languages.  Please can somebody explain me why this piece of code does not work and advise me on how to fix it;

```
<p>Creating and using an object method</p> 
<p id="demoArray"></p>

<script>
  function car(make,model,colour) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.changeCarMake = function (newCarMake) {
      this.make = newCarMake;
    }
  }
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(new car("VW", "Polo", "Red"));
  arr.push(new Car("Mazda", "Z3", "Silver"));
  arr.push(new car("BMW", "Z Series", "Green"));
  var i;
  for (i=0; i < arr.length; i = i + 1) {
    console.log(arr[i].make);
    document.getElementById("demoArray").innerHTML += "Car " + (i + 1) + ": " + arr[i].make + "<br />";
  }
</script>
```

I have copied this from a screenshot of an example that makes up part of the learning requirements of the course that I am on.  I have copied it out several times, checked it, tinkered with it, and tried to research the issue but still I cannot get it to work. All I can get it to do is show the content of the the first paragraph tags.

I found an example on the W3Schools site that seemed to be doing the same thing but using a different syntax, however this is the way that I was given and I am trying to figure this out.

The only thing that I have omitted is that there were two closing script tags one under another in the screenshot example.

I need to know what the issue is before I can dissect and understand the code for myself and apply it to my own evidence (a simple JavaScript web page) to finish this unit.

Thanks.

Cliff.

Comment: Fixed https://jsfiddle.net/5y5qgbkk/

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so make sure you write `new Car` always in the same way, and use the same case for the function name. The `Car`  with capital is the preferred way of naming in this context. Learn to look in the browser's console to see the errors that are being generated.

Comment: in such situations it's always a good practice checking the browser console to make sure there are no syntactical/typo errors just like this one.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the information and the fix.  I am sorry, I have been up all night studying.

Answer (score 2):

The third car you're creating is done with a capital C, which throw an error halting the rest of the script.